# Exception while Setup SageMaker Domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-sagemaker

I have created a user and grant three permissions to it.
IAMFullAccess, AmazonSageMakerFullAccess and AmazonS3FullAccess
Now when i try to setup sagemaker domain, it throw following exceptions

ValidationException
Access denied in getting/accepting the portfolio shared by SageMaker. Please call withservicecatalog:AcceptPortfolioShare & servicecatalog:ListAcceptedPortfolioShares permission.

AccessDeniedException
User: arn:aws:iam::117609614511:user/tac-sagemaker is not authorized to perform: sagemaker:CreateDomain on resource: arn:aws:sagemaker:us-east-1:117609614511:domain/d-bpq1nh2g5t9l because no identity-based policy allows the sagemaker:CreateDomain action

First, I did not understand, though i granted full sagmaker access, why its not picking createDomain policy,

Second, i go to my role and manually added these policies.
Here are policies for my sagemaker role
[image]
**AmazonSageMaker-ExecutionPolicy-20220813T004513**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::s34sagemaker"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::s34sagemaker/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**SagemakerCreateDomain**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sagemaker:CreateDomain",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:sagemaker:*:117609614511:domain/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

**sagemakerportfolioservices**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "servicecatalog:AcceptPortfolioShare",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:catalog:*:117609614511:portfolio/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "servicecatalog:ListAcceptedPortfolioShares",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

But still it giving me same error

**Edit**
I added two new policy to my user
AmazonSageMakerAdmin-ServiceCatalogProductsServiceRolePolicy
AWSServiceCatalogAdminFullAccess

Now ValidationException is gone, but still having AccessDeniedException

**EDIT2:**
I have attached a new custom policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:PassRole",
                "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole",
                "sagemaker:CreateDomain"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

But still the error is same

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to create the domain?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the CloudFormation template in this blog to help create the Domain and User Profile.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/automate-a-centralized-deployment-of-amazon-sagemaker-studio-with-aws-service-catalog/

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your AWS admin needs to grant you access. I was stuck on this as well, and asked my manager to grant access, then I was able to do what I needed to do.